Why is my Leddar Vu 8 sensor dies on roslaunch?
I have Leddar Vu 8 usb model. I installed the LeddarSDK as given in https://leddartech.com/app/uploads/dlm_uploads/2021/08/Install-Guide_SDK-Using-LeddarTech-Sensors-in-Linux_V1.0_EN-2.pdf
My specs:

Microsoft wsl2
Ubuntu 20.04
Ros noetic
when running roslaunch leddar_ros example.launch param1:=/dev/ttyACM0 device_type:=Vu8 param3:=1  param4:=0
it gives the error

  File "/home/aerohod/catkin_ws/src/leddar_ros/scripts/device.py", line 18, in <module>
    import ros_numpy
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/ros_numpy/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import point_cloud2
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/ros_numpy/point_cloud2.py", line 224, in <module>
    def get_xyz_points(cloud_array, remove_nans=True, dtype=np.float):
  File "/home/aerohod/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 305, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(__former_attrs__[attr])
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'.
`np.float` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `float`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `float` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
[LeddarTech_1/sensor-2] process has died [pid 1606, exit code 1, cmd /home/aerohod/catkin_ws/src/leddar_ros/scripts/device.py __name:=sensor __log:=/home/aerohod/.ros/log/4280bb72-fc9a-11ee-974e-07af88f4c2a9/LeddarTech_1-sensor-2.log].
log file: /home/aerohod/.ros/log/4280bb72-fc9a-11ee-974e-07af88f4c2a9/LeddarTech_1-sensor-2*.log
[rviz-4] process has finished cleanly```
rviz opens but does not generate cloud points like shown in the guide.
edited the np.float to float in the device.py file, no use.

